# Unpickling a dictionary inside a function wont save the data

Tags: python-3.x, pickle

i'm using python 3.6 to make a little "saving profile" script in which the dictionary is the profile to be saved . It has two functions to save a profile (dictionary) and load one using the pickle module .

```
import pickle

profile = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
loadedProfile = {} 

def saveProfile():

    profileName = input("Save profile as ... ")
    save = open(profileName + ".pickle","wb")
    pickle.dump(profile,save)
    save.close()

def loadProfile():

    profileName = input("Opem profile ... ")
    load = open(profileName + ".pickle","rb")
    loadedProfile = pickle.load(load)
    load.close()
    print(loadedProfile)

saveProfile()
loadProfile()

print(loadedProfile)
```

The output :

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
{}
```

Notice that inside the function it prints out the loadedProfile as the old dictionary , but the second print outside the function prints an empty dictionary .

What prevents the dictionary data from being saved into a dictionary inside a function ?

Thanks .

Comment: did you input the same data? can you remove the interactive code from your example? oh and you have to make that variable `global` !

Comment: Yes i did . and you were correct i needed to make it a global variable . Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is that when you do:

```
loadedProfile = pickle.load(load)
```

you're creating a local variable with the same name as the global variable (the variable is lost when exiting the function). You need to tell python that you'll be reusing the same name

```
global loadedProfile
loadedProfile = pickle.load(load)
```

Personally, I would *return* such a variable. Relying on globals is generally a bad idea (same for save function):

```
import pickle

profile = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}

def saveProfile(p):

    profileName = input("Save profile as ... ")
    with open(profileName + ".pickle","wb") as save:
        pickle.dump(p,save)


def loadProfile():

    profileName = input("Opem profile ... ")
    with open(profileName + ".pickle","rb") as load:
        loadedProfile = pickle.load(load)

    return loadedProfile

saveProfile(profile)
new_profile = loadProfile()
```

Comment: Thank you for your technical explanation , it solved my problem and i will dig deeper into why globals are bad idea .